# Access phpMyAdmin control panel from external ip

Tags: apache-http-server, phpmyadmin

I have a WD My Cloud that I would like to also use as a mysql database, I have setup port forwarding on my router on port 3306.

When I try to access the mysql database from my C# application using the external ip, it works fine. But I would also like to access the phpMyAdmin control panel using the external ip, so I navigate to:
http://11.11.11.11:3306/phpMyAdmin and I get "ERR_INVALID_HTTP_RESPONSE". (navigating to http://192.168.0.181/phpMyAdmin works from my local network)

The WD My Cloud is running Apache2 so I added this:

```
<Directory "/var/www/phpMyAdmin">
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
Allow from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>
```

to /usr/local/apache2/conf/httpd.conf and I restarted apache, this made no difference.

Can anyone tell me how I can access the phpmyadmin control panel from the external ip?

Thanks!

Comment: Is your Apache configured to listen to port 3306? You probably want to replace 3306 with 80. Or just leave it out.

Answer (score 1):

You're connecting to MySQL instead of Apache (which your browser, for obvious reasons, has no idea what to do with).

Change `http://11.11.11.11:3306/phpMyAdmin` to `http://11.11.11.11:80/phpMyAdmin` (or leave off the port entirely).

Comment: I enabled port forwarding on port 8080 and I tried again, when port 80 wasn't enabled I got "connection refused" and when it is enabled I get "Connection timed out"

Comment: @user265889 Where's port 8080 coming from in all this?

Comment: nvm that, I got it to work but now I get "You don't have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server." I tried different things in httpd.conf and I also tried a .htaccess file but it won't let me access it for some reason

Answer (score -3):

change ip address

```
Allow from 127.0.0.1 to your system ip address
```

Comment: `Allow from all` already covers that.